# Does "Big Stinker" count as "Bad Medicine?"

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I'm currently using the "Big Stinker" rune on my Gargantuan:

> Big Stinker
>   The Gargantuan is surrounded by a poison cloud that deals 15% weapon damage as Poison per second to nearby enemies.

I was considering stacking this with Bad Medicine as a passive:

> Bad Medicine
>   Whenever you deal Poison damage to an enemy, their damage is reduced by 20% for 3 seconds.

This seems like it could be useful to make my Gargantuan even more tank-ish.  However, I don't know if the poison effect counts as poison damage for the purposes of the passive.

Can anyone confirm (via some repeatable test and/or official statement) that this works or doesn't?

Comment: Does Bad Medicine not have a debuff visual effect?

Comment: @RavenDreamer, not that I can tell - there's the poison effect, but  it's the same with or without the passive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I was not able to find an official reply from Blizzard, the current opinion is **yes**: The poison cloud of the Big Stinker rune triggers Bad Medicine.

Several threads exist where people are stating that it works: [[1]](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271499733)[[2]](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150112122)[[3]](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5270830838)[[4]](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150756774)[[5]](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5568798977)[[6]](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5270827473)[[7]](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?830449-Big-Stinker-amp-Bad-Medicine)[[8]](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/43006-gargantuan-big-stinker-bad-medicine-help/)[[9]](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4211086513).